# Pandas float value issues using loc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, floating-accuracy

This might be an easy one for Pandas users used to float numbers but doing my head in and I honestly will appreciate your advise.

I am unable to retrieve the value I saved into the dataframe when using .loc

Can someone please explain and help resolve? Thanks!

```
dict = [{'me': 0.094092328767113}]
df = pandas.DataFrame(dict)
df['me']
Out[32]: 
0    0.094092328767113
Name: me, dtype: float64
df.loc[0,'me']
Out[33]: 0.094092328767113001
```

Comment: You mean the problem is the last three digits?

Comment: @anky_91 - My operation is further calculations so my operations are impacted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use basic string formatting -

```
>>> '{:.15f}'.format(df.loc[0,'me'])
>>> '0.094092328767113'
```

This would result in a string data type. Further, you can convert it to float if you need to using `numpy` as -

```
>>> np.float64('{:.15f}'.format(df.loc[0,'me']))
>>> 0.094092328767113
```

---

The final fix boils down to upgrading the version of Pandas and NumPy as confirmed by OP in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for this. I ran the float version of your solution, but no joy :(
`
df['me']
Out[44]: 
0    0.094092328767113
Name: me, dtype: float64
np.float64('%.15f' % df.loc[0,'me'])
Out[45]: 0.094092328767113001
`

Comment: Which version of Pandas and Numpy are you dealing with?

Comment: pandas.__version__
Out[46]: '0.20.3'

np.__version__
Out[48]: '1.13.1'

Thanks!

Comment: You might update them. I'm using Pandas 0.24 and Numpy 1.16 and as you can see I don't face any such problem.

Comment: Thank you, I upgraded and can get this working. Such a relief!